# Message flow from Queue to Web Service IBM ace

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

So i'm new to queues and flows and i've been practicing only on passing messages through a simple flow in IBM ACE, that sends from a queue to another queue (IBM MQ).
My next task will be to get a message from a Q and send it to a Web Server. I'm struggling to understand what sould i do. Is the output gonna be a SOAP component at the end of the flow ? [image: that's the flow i did for reference]

Comment: You have three options SOAPRequest, RESTRequest, HTTPRequest depends on what kind of interface the target system supports. Note you can use HTTPRequest instead of the SOAPRequest and RESTRequest nodes but then you miss out on all the inbuilt extras that come with those two nodes.

Comment: You can also have a look at these tutorials which I found by searching for github ibm ace https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=enterprise-toolkit-tutorials-github